# Dynamically changed views in a full screen window in Xamain.Mac (monomac)

Tags: cocoa, view, xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

I am trying to figure out a correct composition of views and subviews in Xamarin.Mac (monomac) application.

There are very little examples of Windows/Background View/Controls UI with Xamarin.Mac out there and those which I found (basically [this project](https://github.com/danclarke/AquissUsageChecker) is the best documented one when it comes to Window/View composition) suffer from the same problem - its a static binding of a form Window -> Background view (bound in XCode) -> Controls under the View node. What's being displayed as controls on the view isn't dynamically added via C# and not even a separate view inside the background view.

What I need, is to create a Window, that has a background view that will be semitransparent and then have my application dynamically, depending of the app logic, inject different subviews to background view from C# code. I know that one can add a subview to a view in Xamarin.Mac, but when I try it in my case, the subview just isn't being shown:

GoFullscreen is where the window starts to transform:

```
private void GoFullScreen ()
{
    // Set the window level to be above the menu bar
    Window.Level = NSWindowLevel.Normal;

    var backgroundView = new LeoBreakBackgroundView ();
    backgroundView.SetBreakSubview (_currentBreakViewController);

    Window.ContentView = backgroundView;

    Window.ContentView.EnterFullscreenModeWithOptions (NSScreen.MainScreen, new NSDictionary());

    // Show the window
    Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);
}
```

At the point I call `backgroundView.SetBreakSubview (_currentBreakViewController);`

which is:

```
_currentBreakViewController = currentBreakController;
this.AddSubview (_currentBreakViewController.View);
```

I don't see the _currentBreakViewController.View being added to backgroundView, but the backgroundView is indeed added onto a window that goes fullscreen.

`_currentBreakViewController` is a `NSViewController` and `LeoBreakBackgroundView` you see in the first snippet is just an `NSView` without a controller.

Anyways, is it possible to control a View's subview dynamically from code in Xamarin.Mac?